# Apache POI: content in excel file gets corrupted

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am writing a method which writes to an Excel file. Before calling I create a Workbook and a Sheet. The code executes without any errors, but when opening the created Excel file I get the message: We found a problem with some content in...

My method looks like this:

```
public void writeToCell(int rowNumber, int cellNumber, Double content) {
    Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNumber);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(cellNumber);

    cell.setCellValue(content);

    try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(month + ".xlsx", true)) {
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is how I call the method:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(month);

writeToCell(25, 4, 0.0);
writeToCell(25, 6, 23.32);
```

Comment: Do you close the `outputStream`?

Comment: Yes, after calling the method. I also tried closing it in the method but didn't help.

Comment: Can you also add your code where you are calling writeToCell ?

Comment: Any specific reason for using 25 and 4 ? or 25 and 6 ?

Comment: I am just testing out writing to an excel file. But eventually, I will need to place some numbers around that area for my program.

Comment: You cannot appending data to an Excel Workbook using an FileOutputStream having boolean append true. The method `workbook.write(outputStream);` does always writing the whole workbook to the stream. So what you are doing is writing two complete workbooks to the stream.  You need creating the workbook, creating the worksheets, creating all cells having the data and then writing the workbook **once** using `workbook.write(outputStream);`. See https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Creating+Cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't append data to Excel Workbook explicitly, which also point by @Axel in his comment

```
try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(month + ".xlsx", true))
```

instead

```
try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(month + ".xlsx"))
```

For side note,

```
writeToCell(25, 4, 0.0);
writeToCell(25, 6, 23.32);
```

Last call of `writeToCell` will overwrite the previous value of same 25th row. As, you are create new `Row` in each call

```
Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNumber);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way in which I am able to append content to the excel file via the Apache POI library?

Comment: @Stijn It will append data in each call, but you need to make sure you are not create same row again, else it will overwrite previous one

Comment: Ok I see what you are saying. I tried writing one cell to row 25 and the other to 26, but the problem remains. Could there be another mistake in my code?

Comment: @Stijn Are you sure, you removed append flag ? and called something similar `writeToCell(24, 0, 4.0);
        writeToCell(25, 5, 23.32);` ?

Comment: @Stijn I'm using exact your code and with changes which I suggested in my post and I'm able to see changes in excel file. Also, make sure, you are looking at correct file.

Comment: Yes, I removed the append flag and changed the first parameter of my second call to 26.

Comment: @Stijn Remove existing excel file and run your code again and check if files gets generated. If you are still getting same issue, then you have some bug in your code, you should verify yourself. For now, whatever code your have provided will get corrected with my solution. If you still have issue, then you need to post different question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162165/discussion-between-stijn-and-ravi).

Answer (score 0):

I had also that error, it happened that in some cells the cell content type and the cell value didn't match.